# Socket IO won't function on Openshift

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, openshift

Using the following server code:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io');

//  Set the environment variables we need.
ipaddress = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP;
port      = process.env.OPENSHIFT_INTERNAL_PORT || process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || 8080;

if (typeof ipaddress === "undefined") {
//  Log errors on OpenShift but continue w/ 127.0.0.1 - this
//  allows us to run/test the app locally.
console.warn('No OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP var, using 127.0.0.1');
ipaddress = "127.0.0.1";
};

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendfile('index.html');
});

http.listen(process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT, process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP, function(){
console.log('listening on *:' + port + ", " + ipaddress);
});
```

I am simply attempting to include the socket.io module in my code, not even initializing io, and my code is having an error when attempting to start the app on Openshift.  When I remove "var io = require('socket.io');" my app launches fine.

When I SSH'ed into my server space and looked in the node_modules, it looked as though Openshift hadn't installed socketio even though I had included it in my package.

Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "OpenShift-Sample-App",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "OpenShift Sample Application",
  "keywords": [
    "OpenShift",
    "Node.js",
    "application",
    "openshift"
  ],
  "author": {
    "name": "OpenShift",
    "email": "ramr@example.org",
    "url": "http://www.openshift.com/"
  },
  "homepage": "http://www.openshift.com/",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/openshift/origin-server"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 0.6.0",
    "npm": ">= 1.0.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.10.2",
"socket.io": "^1.3.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "bundleDependencies": [],
  "private": true,
  "main": "server.js"
}
```

During the git push to Openshift it indicates that all packages, including socketio, install OK.

Any idea how I can get the socketio module functioning correctly on Openshift?

Comment: whats is the npm version? you can SSH and use command `npm -v` to check

Answer (score 0):

it looks like older npm versions had problem with npm install because of caret character

Try replacing dependencies as below in `package.json`

```
"dependencies": {
  "express": "4.10.2",
  "socket.io": "1.3.7"
},
```